# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' to type 'ProfileCommon'

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a blank profile for one of the member object and I am seeing the error above.

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile' to type 'ProfileCommon'."

Anybody any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`ProfileCommon` [inherits from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx) the `ProfileBase` class
`DefaultProfile` also [inherits from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.defaultprofile%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) `ProfileBase` class

Comment: Yeah, but what's the problem that it is facing now? I tried inheriting it from ProfileBase as well and still did not work....